# How do you create 3D objects in Microsoft Visio?

Tags: windows, images, microsoft-visio

How can I create a 3D object in Visio? By 3D, I mean a diagram or graphic that has a z-axis like a cube or pyramid. Not like a normal square or flat 2D shape (which has only the x and y axes).

I don't want to use the ones given in map template.

Comment: Tell us what you mean by "3d projections".  There is some limited 3D stuff, just not sure if it is what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919618/3d-equivalent-to-visio/919636#919636).